# Finding Mising Values from a set of numbers in excel

Tags: excel

I have excel data with 1.3 million rows of data. 
The data is from transport booking table. It has a booking booklet number with 50 leafs in each booklet so lets say the number could be 1234001 to 1234050 as one booklet. Similarly there are now 10000 booklets with 50 leafs in each. 
There are few entries missing in each or some of the booklets. Hence I need to filter out only those leafs where the values are missing. What is the fastest way to achieve this.

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Comment: This is not to answer without further descriptions. The 1.3 million rows can't be in one sheet as there are maximum 1048576 rows possible. So how is the Excel workbook organized? And "to filter out only those leafs where the values are missing" implies that there are other fields filled in those rows except the booking booklet number, which is missing. Is this so? What fields are this? And how then can be defined which booking booklet number this should be?

Answer (score 0):

Sort the column with leaf numbers in A to Z order, insert a new column beside this.

lets say if leaf numbers are in B column sort b column from A to z and insert a column after b or if b column is empty put a formula in c2 as =b3-b2

if the difference is greater than 1 then some leafs are missing in between

Comment: Hi All,
As there was 1.3 million rows of data hence 2 excel files were created to accommodate the data.However for the period in question i filtered it out to approx 94000 rows of data.
Now there are 3 columns- 
A)Booklet start number - 21939701
B)Booklet end number - 21939750
IN each booklet there are 50 leafs & there are unique 4068 booklets which makes 203400 observations. But there are some numbers missing from each booklet- this could be 1st, 10th, 50th, 35th number from the leaf.
Hence I need to create a column which should populate only the missing values.